# Qt Play/Pause Action?

Tags: qt, action

What's the best way to go about creating a play/pause button in Qt? Should I create one action and change it's icon when clicked, or should I create two actions and then somehow hide one when clicked? How do I use one shortcut key to activate both actions? (Pause when playing, or play when paused).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Keep it simple**. Use the same button, but when handling the clicking, change the icon and choose the handling logic (play or pause) based on current status (pause when playing or playing when paused).

In order to keep the code clear, implement two separate methods, one for play and one for pause and call them from the slot of the button, depeding on the status.

Comment: I would actually have to change the icon, the text, the status tip, the slot, and instead of calling the play() or pause() slots directly, I'd have to call a function in the same class to update the button, and then propagate the action... makes more sense to have two actions which you can switch so you don't have to manage changing all those properties.

Comment: To me, it looks simpler to have a conditional call in a single slot method, than disconnecting and reconnecting a slot... But maybe it is a matter of prefference :)

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to disc/reconnect if you had two separate actions, no? I didn't realize you meant one slot for both actions though... that *might* work better. Have to think about this ab it more.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this is easiest/most appropriate:

```
playAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/icons/elementary/media-playback-start.png"), tr("&Run"), controlActGroup);
playAct->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Space);
playAct->setCheckable(true);
playAct->setStatusTip(tr("Run physics"));
connect(playAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), editorView, SLOT(runPhysics()));

pauseAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/icons/elementary/media-playback-pause.png"), tr("&Pause"), controlActGroup);
pauseAct->setShortcut(Qt::Key_Space);
pauseAct->setCheckable(true);
pauseAct->setStatusTip(tr("Pause physics"));
connect(pauseAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), editorView, SLOT(pausePhysics()));

connect(playAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), pauseAct, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
connect(pauseAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), playAct, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));
pauseAct->setChecked(true);
pauseAct->setVisible(false);
```

The only thing I don't like is that the actions are controlling the OTHER button's visibility status. Since there is no `setInvisible` function I couldn't hook it up so that they could hide themselves when clicked.

That, and it seems to create a visual gap where the hidden button was (at least on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

You can add both play and pause actions to the toolbar and to the menu of the main window and make the pause action invisible. When you need to switch this actions you will only have to change visibility of the actions and it takes affect on menu and on toolbar simultaneously. It's convenient, code is compact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your play/pause buttons are doing, but I'm building an app with Phonon to stream audio and I couldn't find a good way to get the current state of the media object.

The closest I could get is to create a slot and connect it to the `stateChanged()` signal that `MediaObject` emits. I ended up doing this:

```
    MyMediaPlayer::MyMediaPlayer(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MyMediaPlayer)
    {
        ...

        connect(mediaObj, SIGNAL(stateChanged(Phonon::State,Phonon::State)),
                this, SLOT(handleMediaState(Phonon::State,Phonon::State)));
    }

...

void MyMediaPlayer::handleMediaState(Phonon::State state, Phonon::State)
{
    switch (state)
    {
    case Phonon::PlayingState:
    case Phonon::LoadingState:
    case Phonon::BufferingState:
        //If we're playing, the button should pause
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-pause.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                mediaObj, SLOT(pause()));
        break;
    case Phonon::PausedState:
    case Phonon::StoppedState:
        //if we're paused, the button should play
        ui->playPauseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/assets/stock_media-play.svg"));
        connect(ui->playPauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                mediaObj, SLOT(play()));
    case Phonon::ErrorState:
        //additionally, if there's an error, do error handling.
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of connecting and re-connecting, but I guess this is the Qt way to do it.